# Polars Python not converting to Datetime format when parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, parsing, python-polars

Like the title says, I don't know why it's not converting to datetime.

```
df = pl.read_csv(file, ignore_errors=True, parse_dates=True)
df.columns = list(map(lambda x: x.replace(' ', ''), df.columns))
df_new = df.select(pl.col(['Date_Convert','Region']))
print(df_new.head())
```

shape: (5, 2)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tioX.png)

I tried doing it without parsing on load. Here's the outcome:

```
df = df.with_columns(pl.col('Date_Convert').str.strptime(pl.Datetime, strict=False, fmt='%Y/%B/%d %H:%M'))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLnlY.png)

Comment: The `fmt` you've used does not match your data. `%B` is the month name and the year is in the wrong place. It should be `fmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'` or `fmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'` It also helps if you provide your example data/dataframe in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this one by changing the region in my machine that has a date format of yyyy-mm-dd (Canada).

This is basically from:
mm-dd-yyyy
To:
yyyy-mm-dd

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_csv.html) says

```
try_parse_dates

    Try to automatically parse dates. Most ISO8601-like time zone naive formats can be inferred, as well as a handful of others. If this does not succeed, the column remains of data type pl.Utf8. If use_pyarrow=True, dates will always be parsed.
```

So, not all formats can be automatically inferred without a format.

You're on the right track though - first just read the csv, and then convert to datetime using `strptime` and passing the format explicitly